# Give closest elements class from siblings string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few tr elements that are divided by a category header - I want to add the class from the a elements string to the tr class below and to repeat this trough out. the .keep elements can vary in amount.

How do I do this the best way?

```
<tr>
 <td class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6”>
  <a href="">Drives</a
 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="keep”> - should add class .drives
</tr>

<tr class="keep”> - should add class .drives
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6”>
  <a href=“">Memory</a
 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="keep”> - should add class .memory
</tr>

<tr class="keep”> - should add class .memory
</tr>
```

Comment: `$('a').closest('tr').addClass($('a').html())` try this

Comment: All td with an <a> element has class "unfoldedlabel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var title = "";
$( "table tr" ).each(function( index ) {
    if($(this).find("a").length == 1) {
        title = $(this).find("td").find("a").text();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass(title.toLowerCase());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$( ".unfoldedlabel a" ).click(function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil('tr:has(.unfoldedlabel)').addClass( $(this).html().toLowerCase() );
})
```

Comment: This is `nextUntil` :) and btw it is checking for siblings only, so it could be: `.nextUntil('tr:has(.unfoldedlabel)')`

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for correcting me. Missed that this `.unfoldedlabel` is at td level not tr.